# Keypress not working in IE (Keydown and Keyup posting the form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, keypress

I am working in a form. In which I have used validate plugin to show validation messages. If the user press enter key, I have to validate the form and show if the name is already exists.

```
$('#name').bind("keypress", function (e) {
    $("#valid_name").parent("span").removeClass("has-error");
    $("#valid_name").text("");
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Validate();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code is woking fine in chrome and firefox. I need to clear the validation message which i shown manually without using plugin. But this event not triggering in IE.
If I use keydown/keyup the form will be posted without showing validation message. Hence duplicate names will be added in portal.

Can anyone suggest fix for this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() outside if condition.

Comment: If I use e.preventDefault() outside if condition, I couldn't event type in textbox in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) should work in all cases. You can even test that it's working in your browser from the doc page.

If you want to dive into details, [that page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) has lots of infos, especially for older IE versions, and also includes a [nice test script](http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html).

Comment: I have changed e.keycode to e.which. But not triggering in IE. $('#name').bind("keypress", function (e) {
    $("#valid_name").parent("span").removeClass("has-error");
    $("#valid_name").text("");
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Validate();
        return false;
    }
});

Comment: @Shesha Did you test with the jQuery doc page ?